# Random Password Function Fails To Validate

Tags: php, mysql, random, pdo, passwords

I'm trying to create a web application that randomizes the type of password a user is requested before login. The registration page does not hash the password, and I don't really need to hash it for this demo. When a user is logging in, they first provide their email address, which is comfirmed from the database. 
The page code is as below(index.php):

```
<?php
    require_once 'dbconnect.php';

    /*
    if ( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ) {
        header("Location: home.php");
        exit;
    }
    */

    $error = false;

    if( isset($_POST['btn-login']) ) {
        $email = sanitize($_POST['email']);

        if(empty($email)){
            $error = true;
            $emailError = "Please enter your email address.";
        } else if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
            $error = true;
            $emailError = "Please enter valid email address.";
        }
        if (!$error) {

            $stmt = dbconnect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email");
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ":email" => $email,
            ));
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();

            if($count == 1) {
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    redirect('creds.php');

            } else {
                $errMSG = "Incorrect Credentials, Try again...";
            }

        }

    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Coding Cage - Login & Registration System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div id="login-form">
    <form method="post" autocomplete="off">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <h2 class="">Sign In.</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <hr />
            </div>
            <?php
            if ( isset($errMSG) ) {
                ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?php echo $errMSG; ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }

            ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" value="<?php if (isset($email)) {echo $email;} ?>" maxlength="40" />
                </div>
                <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset ($emailError)) {echo $emailError;} ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <hr />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="btn-login">Next..</button>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <hr />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <a href="register.php">Sign Up Here...</a>
            </div>

        </div>

    </form>
    </div>  

</div>

</body>
</html
```

After filling out that form, the user is redirected to **'creds.php'** which is supposed to select a random password function from **functions.php**.
The **creds.php** code is:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconnect.php';


/*
if ( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ) {
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit;
}
*/


$error = false;

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']) ) {
    $pass = sanitize($_POST['pass']);

    $passarray = getrandomfunction($pass);

    echo $passarray;
    if ($passarray == 0)
    {
        $passval = 'reversepass';
    }
    elseif ($passarray == 1)
    {
        $passval = 'passtoupper';
    }
    elseif ($passarray == 2)
    {
        $passval = 'passtolower';
    }
    elseif ($passarray == 3)
    {
        $passval = 'defaultpass';
    }
    elseif ($passarray == 4)
    {
        $passval = 'passfirst4letter';
    }
    $eg = $passval;

    if(empty($pass)){
        $error = true;
        $passError = "Please enter your password.";
    }

    if (!$error) {
        $stmt = dbconnect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email");
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ":email" => $_SESSION['email'],
        ));
        $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();


        if( $count == 1 ) { /* && $passfrmdbffunc==$passfromfunc */
            foreach ($row as  $row)
            {

                //echo $eg;
                $dbpassword = $row['password']; //from db
                //$passfromfunc   = $eg($pass);
                $passfrmdbffunc = $eg($dbpassword);  // fromdb processed
                echo $pass . '<br/>';
                //echo $passfrmdbffunc;

                switch ($passarray)
                {
                    case 0;
                        if ($pass != reversepass($dbpassword))
                        {
                            $errMSG = "Incorrect revese Credentials, Try again...";
                        }
                        else{
                            $_SESSION['logged'] = True;
                            redirect('home.php');
                        }
                    break;
                    case 1:
                        if ($pass != passtoupper($dbpassword))
                        {
                            $errMSG = "Incorrect upper Credentials, Try again...";
                        }
                        else{
                            $_SESSION['logged'] = True;
                            redirect('home.php');
                        }
                    break;
                    case 2;
                        if ($pass != passtolower($dbpassword))
                        {
                            $errMSG = "Incorrect lower Credentials, Try again...";
                        }
                        else{
                            $_SESSION['logged'] = True;
                            redirect('home.php');
                        }
                    break;
                    case 3;
                        if ($pass !== defaultpass($dbpassword))
                        {
                            $errMSG = "Incorrect default Credentials, Try again...";
                        }
                        else{
                            $_SESSION['logged'] = True;
                            redirect('home.php');
                        }
                    break;
                    case 4;
                        if ($pass != passfirst4letter($dbpassword))
                        {
                            $errMSG = "Incorrect 4letter Credentials, Try again...";
                        }
                        else{
                            $_SESSION['logged'] = True;
                            redirect('home.php');
                        }
                    break;
                }

                /*
                if ($passfrmdbffunc == $pass)
                {
                    $_SESSION['logged'] = True;
                    //redirect('home.php');
                }
                else
                {
                    $errMSG = "Incorrect Credentials, Try again...";
                }*/
            }
        } else {
            $errMSG = "Incorrect Credentials, Try again...";
        }

    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Password <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div id="login-form">
        <form method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h2 class="">Provide your password in <?php if (isset($passarray)){echo $passval;}?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <hr />
                </div>
                <?php
                if ( isset($errMSG) ) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?php echo $errMSG; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                        <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Password" maxlength="15" />
                    </div>
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($passError)) {echo $passError;} ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <hr />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="btn-login">Sign In</button>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <hr />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="register.php">Sign Up Here...</a>
                </div>

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html
```

I am using PDO-Mysql driver to interact with the database.
Oh, and the **functions.php** code that randomizes the passwords is:

```
<?php
function reversepass($password)
{
    return strrev($password);
}

function passtoupper($password)
{
    return strtoupper($password);
}

function passtolower($password)
{
    return strtolower($password);
}

function defaultpass($password)
{
    return $password;
}

function passfirst4letter($password)
{
    return substr($password, 0, 4);
}

function getrandomfunction($password)
{
    $functions = array(reversepass($password),passtoupper($password),passtolower($password),defaultpass($password),passfirst4letter($password));
    return array_rand(array_keys($functions));
}
?>
```

My problem is that the password form may request 'reverse password' but when you provide the password in reverse, instead of returning true, it returns the result of the next random function. I need it to redirect and set a session if the return value is true, else show the error message.

**Edit**
The database file has the sanitize function:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();


function dbconnect()
{
    $db_host   = '127.0.0.1';
    $db_user   = 'root';
    $dbname    = 'project';
    $db_pass   = '';

    try{
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$dbname",$db_user, $db_pass);
        // set PDO error mode to exception
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo 'Connection to the database failed ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $connection;
}

function sanitize($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

    return $data;
}

function redirect($url)
{
    header("Location: $url");
}

include_once 'functions.php';
?>
```

Comment: and where is this method? `sanitize()` and what does it do? or is that irrelevant? can't see why you'd want an additional method since you're using a prepared statement

Comment: What type of application is this where this is necessary? I, as a user, would be very annoyed if asked to enter anything other than what I entered as my password, as my password

Comment: `function sanitize($data)` you don't need that, nor should you use that. A prepared statement is enough.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i i included the dbconnect.php file with the sanitize function..

Answer (score 0):

The logic you use in `creds.php` is incorrect.
This is what you do now:

1. Load the page -> with no password validation criteria selected
2. User inserts password -> send form
3. Now you select a random criteria -> but it's AFTER the user sent you the password, so it's likely that it doesn't match
4. User gets an error message and the new criteria for password
5. User sends form with new password
6. But now you create a new criteria -> and again it doesn't match...

Problem is 3 and 6...
So, the solution is to create the criteria for password validation BEFORE you show the form and SAVE it in SESSION for later access.

I would change your `functions.php` to this (simplified)

```
<?php

$PASSWORD_MODES = array(
  "reversepass", "passtoupper", "passtolower", "defaultpass", "passfirst4letter"
);
$RANDOM_MODE = $PASSWORD_MODES[rand(0, count($PASSWORD_MODES)-1)];

function changePasswordByMode($mode, $password) {
    switch ($mode) {
        case "reversepass":
            return strrev($password);
            break;
        case "passtoupper":
            return strtoupper($password);
            break;
        case "passtolower":
            return strtolower($password);
            break;
        case "passfirst4letter":
            return substr($password, 0, 4);
            break;
        case "defaultpass":
            return $password;
            break;
        default:
            return $password;
            break;
    }
}

function validatePasswordMode($original_password, $mode, $test_password) {
    return $test_password === changePasswordByMode($mode, $original_password);
}

?>
```

And this is `creds.php` (simplified):

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconnect.php';
/*
  SET VARS
 */
$error = $pass = $errMSG = $passError = false;
global $RANDOM_MODE;
/*
  CHECK POST FOR $pass
 */
if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
  $pass = sanitize($_POST['pass']);
  if(empty($pass)){
    $error = true;
    $passError = "Please enter your password.";
   }
}
/*
  IF $pass IS PROVIDED & $_SESSION["passmode"] IS SET -> VALIDATE
 */
if ($pass && isset($_SESSION["passmode"])) {
  $stmt = dbconnect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email");
  $stmt->execute(array(
    ":email" => $_SESSION['email'],
  ));
  $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
  $count = $stmt->rowCount();

  if ($count == 1 ) {
    $dbpassword = $row[0]['password'];

    $VALID_PASS = validatePasswordMode(
      $row[0]['password'], 
      $_SESSION["passmode"],
      $test_password);

    if ($VALID_PASS) {
      $_SESSION['logged'] = TRUE;
      redirect('home.php');
    } else {
      $error = true;
      $errMSG = "Incorrect credentials. Try again...";
    }
  } // endif $count
} // endif $pass && isset($_SESSION["passmode"]))
/*
  SET PASSMODE
*/
$_SESSION["passmode"] = $RANDOM_MODE;
// 
?>
<!-- in your HTML change this part: -->
<div class="form-group">
  <h2 class="">
    Provide your password in <?php echo $_SESSION["passmode"]; ?>
  </h2>
</div>
<!-- keep the rest -->
```